# content inside zip file

Tags: c#, .net, zip

how to find list of files inside zip file without unzipping it in c#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ZIP a file in C#, using no 3rd-party APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940582/how-do-i-zip-a-file-in-c-using-no-3rd-party-apis)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/):

```
ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(path));
ZipEntry item;
while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

Comment: is it possible without sharpziplib.

Comment: @Niraj Choubey: yes, with some other ZIP library (like http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) ..... or you have to re-create the whole ZIP code yourself just to peek inside the ZIP file....

Comment: maybe the `System.IO` will support ZIP archives natively in a future version of the .NET framework - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2010/06/28/working-with-zip-files-in-net.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple way to do this with [sharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) :

```
        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile(@"C:\Test.zip"))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry entry in zipFile)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Name);
            }
        }
```